# Adding custom metadata to jpeg files

Tags: c++, metadata, jpeg

I'm working on an Image processing project(C++) and I need to write custom metadata to jpeg file after the processing is complete. How  can I accomplish this? Is there any library available to do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're talking about EXIF Metadata you may want to look at [exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) which is a C++ library for processing EXIF metadata. There is a second lib which is called [libexif](http://libexif.sourceforge.net/) and is written in C.

Exiv2 has a view examples on their website and a the API is well documented.

UPDATE: If you want to add custom metadata you could either use the `MakerNote` or the `Comment` tag.

Exif Standard: [PDF](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf) see Section 4.6.5 EXIF IFD Attribute Information Table 7, Tags Relating to User Information.

```
     MakerNote    Type Undefined Count Any
     Comment      Type Undefined Count Any
```

which means you're allowed to use those 2 tags for any data you want.

Comment: is it possible to create custom tags using exiv2 ?

Comment: just updated my answer, you could use the `MakerNote` or the `Comment` tag. I'll add a link to the EXIF Standard

Comment: Exiv2 allows you to add custom tags under the XMP section.