# Is it possible to include extra information in an image file that won't corrupt it?

Tags: java, image

I'm making a Java program that I'd like to be able to add extra information to an image file (just plain text, that could later be read by the same program). I was considering adding it a s the first line.

Is there a way to add information like this w/o corrupting the image file. Can I somehow "comment" off that text so it wouldn't be read as part of the image binary (like when you open an image up in Notepad, it would show up there).

Answer (score 2):

This is tagged as Java, but in general, you can modify the [EXIF data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) of an image file.

See also: http://frickelblog.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/java-library-for-reading-writing-exif-xmp-and-iptc-in-jpegs/

Answer (score 2):

Most image file formats allow arbitrary metadata.  PNG image contain pixel data, color profiles, copyright etc etc etc in "chunks" - see http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html for descriptions.  You probably want a iTXt or tEXt chunk.

JPEG also allows metadata.  Read up on JFIF and EXIF.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699613/10468

See the question [Writing image metadata in Java, preferably PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6495518/10468) for some Java-specific answers.

There might also be useful information for you in [Find JPEG resolution with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/262090/10468) although that question asks about PHP not Java.

TIFF isn't seen as much these days, but that format allows for a wide variety of extra data and user-defined tags for any data you like to store.

There are no image file format I know of that you can open in a text editor or print at the command line, which will show as text metadata and not gibberish from the pixels.  However, it is possible to define such a file format - if the file starts off in text, has an EOT (ascii 03) (iirc) then continues in binary, most text command line tools and possibly text editors will deal with the text fine and stop at the EOT.   I'm not sure that works on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Image Stagenography for hiding text. Here are some links which can help you in doing this : [Images' Steganography](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18791/Images-Steganography)

[Steganography - Hiding messages in the Noise of a Picture](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4877/Steganography-Hiding-messages-in-the-Noise-of-a-Pi)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I explain the algorithm:

1. You need to make a mask to make the last bit of the lowest significant bits of your image to zero. Do it first with one bit and see the impact on your image. Then change two last bits to zero and see how your image is impacted. Continue this to figure out how many bits you can turn to zero without any impact on the quality of your image.
2. Get the binary content of your text message.
3. Calculate the length of the binary content of your text message. You need this to save this value in the first few bytes of your image. You will later use it to know how many pixels you need to read to retrieve your message.

Here is the main part:

4. Let's say if you are making only the last bit of your image to zero, and you reserve the first 16 bits for your message length, then you will need the first 16 pixels reserved to save the length of your message. Save the binary value of your message length, for example bin(114), in the last bit of the first 16 pixels. You may need to pad zeros to right to make it match.
5. From pixel 17, start saving your message bit by bit in the last bit of every pixel.
6. To retrieve the embedded message, read the first 16 pixels, construct the length to know how many pixels you need to read to reconstruct your message.

You can even save another image or voice signal inside your image. I know this post is tagged Java, but to give you an idea you can have a look at my python code implementing the same thing in [this_github_link](https://github.com/ErfanEbrahimiBazaz/FAD_HW_Ses4), in file "stagenography_embed_text_in_image.py". Also I have explained the algorithm to save other types of information in this [stackoverflow_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64978571/image-steganography-with-python-opencv-reconstructing-the-embedded-image-is-ver).

Hope it makes it clear.