# Image Steganography with python opencv, reconstructing the embedded image is very noisy

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, steganography

I am hiding an image inside another image (Image Steganography) by using python 3.6.8 with opencv 4.4.0.44. I am on windows 10 machine.

The algorithm I am using is as follows: I have defined a mask with zeros at the last two lowest significant bits. Then I use this mask and "bitwise and" it to make the last two bits of every pixel in the base image to zero. There are two images, one is base image which accommodates the second image (hidden image). I have made sure the size of the hidden image is at most 1/4 of the base image. I have also changed both images in gray-scale to deal with only one channel.

I have successfully embedded the image as well as extracting it, but the extracted image is very noisy, which is surprising for me as the content of the image has not changed.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import os


def mask_n_bit_of_image(img_array, mask):
    """
    Applies a mask bitwise on an image to make the n lowest bit zero
    :param img: input image
    :param mask: mask to make the n lowest significant bits zero. Maske sample: int('11111110', 2)
    :return: masked image
    """
    for i in range(img_array.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img_array.shape[1]):
            new_value = img_array[i, j] & mask
            img_array[i, j] = new_value

    return img_array


def draw_img_side_by_side(img1, img2, caption):
    h_im = cv.hconcat([img_cp, img])
    cv.imshow(caption, h_im)


def image_binary_content(input_array):
    """
   Calculates the binary content of an input numpy array of type int.
   :param input_array: input numpy array which is a gray_scale image
   :return: binary content of the image in str format
   """

    img_cp = []
    for x in range(0, input_array.shape[0]):
        for y in range(0, input_array.shape[1]):
            img_cp.append(bin(int(input_array[x, y]))[2:])

    # reshaping the list to match the image size and order
    new_img_arr = np.reshape(img_cp, (input_array.shape[0], input_array.shape[1]))
    return new_img_arr


def padding_zeros_to_make_8bits_images(input_image):
    """
    Checks the output of image_binary_content(img) to add zeros to the left hand side of every byte.
    It makes sure every pixel is represented by 8 bytes
    :param input_image: input image or numpy 2D array
    :return: numpy 2D array of 8-bits pixels in binary format
    """
    for i in range(input_image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(input_image.shape[1]):
            if len(input_image[i, j]) < 8:
                # print(input_image[i, j])
                zeros_to_pad = 8 - len(input_image[i, j])
                # print('Zeros to pad is {}'.format(zeros_to_pad))
                elm = input_image[i, j]
                for b in range(zeros_to_pad):
                    elm = '0' + elm
                # print('New value is {} '.format(elm))
                input_image[i, j] = elm
                # print('double check {} '.format(input_image[i, j]))

    return input_image



def write_img(path, name, img):
    """

    :param path:
    :param name:
    :param img:
    :return:
    """
    name = os.path.join(path, name)
    cv.imwrite(name, img)



img_path = 's2.bmp'

img = cv.imread(img_path, 0)
cv.imshow('original image', img)
img_cp = img.copy()
path_dest = r'color'
print('Original image shape {}'.format(img.shape))


mask = int('11111100', 2)
print('mask = {}'.format(mask))
img_n2 = mask_n_bit_of_image(img, mask)
# draw_img_side_by_side(img_cp, img_n2, 'Modified image n=2')

img_to_hide_path = r'2.jpeg'
img_to_hide = cv.imread(img_to_hide_path, 0)
img_to_hide = cv.resize(img_to_hide, (220, 220), interpolation=cv.INTER_NEAREST)


# for images which are bigger than 1/4 of the base image, resize them:
# img_to_hide = cv.resize(img_to_hide, (500, 420), interpolation=cv.INTER_NEAREST)


cv.imshow('hidden image', img_to_hide)

h_flat = img_to_hide.flatten()
print('LENGTH OF FLAT HIDDEN IMAGE IS {}'.format(len(h_flat)))
# for i in range(len(h_flat)):
#     print(bin(h_flat[i]))

img_hidden_bin = image_binary_content(img_to_hide)
print('binary of hidden image type: {}'.format(type(img_hidden_bin)))
# reformat evey byte of the hidden image to have 8 bits pixels
img_hidden_bin = padding_zeros_to_make_8bits_images(img_hidden_bin)
print(img_hidden_bin.shape)

all_pixels_hidden_img = img_hidden_bin.flatten()

print('Length of flattened hidden image to embed is {}'.format(len(all_pixels_hidden_img)))
# for i in range(0, 48400):
#     print(all_pixels_hidden_img[i])

num_pixels_to_modify = len(all_pixels_hidden_img) * 4
print('Number of pixels to modify in base image is {}'.format(num_pixels_to_modify))

# parts = [your_string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(your_string), n)]
two_bit_message_list = []
for row in all_pixels_hidden_img:
    for i in range(0, 8, 2):
        two_bit_message_list.append(row[i: i+2])
print('TWO BITS MESSAGE LIST LENGTH {}'.format(len(two_bit_message_list)))

# reconstruct the hidden msg to make sure for the next part
# c_h_img = []
# for i in range(0, len(two_bit_message_list), 4):
#     const_byte = two_bit_message_list[i] + two_bit_message_list[i+1] + two_bit_message_list[i+2] + two_bit_message_list[i+3]
#     c_h_img.append(const_byte)
#
# print('constructed image length c_h_img {}'.format(len(c_h_img)))
# for i in range(48400):
#     print(c_h_img[i])
# c_h_img = np.array(c_h_img, np.float64)
# c_h_img = c_h_img.reshape(img_to_hide.shape)
# cv.imshow('C_H_IMG', c_h_img.astype('uint16'))

# insert 6 zeros to left hand side of every entry to two_bit_message_list
new_hidden_image = []
for row in two_bit_message_list:
    row = '000000' + row
    new_hidden_image.append(row)

base_img_flat = img_cp.flatten()
num_bytes_to_fetch = len(two_bit_message_list)
img_base_flat = img_n2.flatten()
print('LENGTH OF TWO BIT MSG LIST {}'.format(num_bytes_to_fetch))

print('Bit length of the bytes to fetch is {} '.format(bin(num_bytes_to_fetch)))
# scanned from new constructed image
print(bin(num_bytes_to_fetch)[2:])
print(len( bin(num_bytes_to_fetch)[2:] ))



print('Start of loop to embed the hidden image in base image')
for i in range(num_bytes_to_fetch):
    # First 12 bytes are reserved for the hidden image size to be embedded
    new_value = img_base_flat[i] | int( new_hidden_image[i], 2)
    img_base_flat[i] = new_value

image_with_hidden_img = img_base_flat.reshape(img_n2.shape)
cv.imshow('Image with hidden image embedded', image_with_hidden_img)



# Reading embedded image from constructed image
constructed_image_with_message_embedded = image_binary_content(image_with_hidden_img)
constructed_image_with_message_embedded_zero_padded = padding_zeros_to_make_8bits_images(constructed_image_with_message_embedded)
flat_constructed_image_with_message_embedded = constructed_image_with_message_embedded_zero_padded.flatten()

embedded_img_list = []
for i in range(num_bytes_to_fetch):
    embedded_img_list.append(flat_constructed_image_with_message_embedded[i][-2:])

# [print(rec) for rec in embedded_img_list]
print('EMBEDDED IMAGE LIST LENGTH {}'.format(len(embedded_img_list)))

const_byte_list = []
for i in range(0, len(embedded_img_list), 4):
    const_byte = embedded_img_list[i] + embedded_img_list[i+1] + embedded_img_list[i+2] + embedded_img_list[i+3]
    const_byte_list.append(const_byte)

# [print(rec) for rec in const_byte_list]
print('LENGTH OF CONSTRUCT BYTES IS {}'.format(len(const_byte_list)))

const_byte_list_tmp = np.array(const_byte_list, np.float64)
const_byte_2D_array = const_byte_list_tmp.reshape(img_to_hide.shape)  #((220,220))
const_byte_2D_array = const_byte_2D_array.astype('uint16')
cv.imshow('Constructed image from base', const_byte_2D_array)
cv.imwrite('reconstructed_image.jpeg', const_byte_2D_array)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

s2.bmp

[image: s2.bmp]

2.jpeg

[image: 2.jpeg]

I have tried different image extensions including jpg, png, and bmp. In all of them the reconstructed image was distorted. In the image below you can see how noisy the reconstructed image is. The image of nature is the base image containing hidden image in its lsb, the upper eye is the hidden image, the lower eye is the reconstructed hidden image.

[image: Base image with hidden image embedded inside, together with hidden image and reconstructed version of hidden image]

**My own thoughts:** As I got this problem for different image types, and as you see in my code there is a block I have commented (starting at line 134 in github), I think the source of the problem should lay at method "image_binary_content". If you uncomment the block at line 134, you will get the exact same reconstructed image even before embedding it in base image. I made comparisons and I am pretty sure the content of hidden image is correctly retrieved, but before being embedded some data has lost.

My code is as follows and available at this [github_link](https://github.com/ErfanEbrahimiBazaz/FAD_HW_Ses4) under the name `hw3_task1_embed_image_in_base_image.py`. The base and hidden image are also available there. You can also find the reconstructed hidden image after processing it from the base image under the name "reconstructed_image.png" (by screenshot), "reconstructed_image.jpeg" by cv.imwrite. Interestingly what I saved by imwrite has much lower quality than what is shown by running the code.

Comment: I've edited your code here to load the images directly. This is more preferable than telling us to go to github and apply these changes ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of `const_byte_list` are equivalent to those in `all_pixels_hidden_img`, which are the secret image pixels in binary string form. Your error comes shortly after, with

```
const_byte_list_tmp = np.array(const_byte_list, np.float64)
```

You may think that this convert the binary string '11001000' to the value 200, but actually it turns it to the float number 11001000.0. Instead, you want the following

```
const_byte_list_tmp = np.array([int(pixel, 2) for pixel in const_byte_list], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Notice how the array is set to type uint8 and not uint16.

---

Having said all that, you're going about this the wrong way. You've used a BITAND operation somewhere, so you know about bitwise operations. And this is how steganography should be done, with these operations acting on integers. Deep down 0b11111111, 255 and 0xff are all representations of the same number. You don't have to convert integers to binary string, cut and stitch them and then turn them back to integers.

Numpy also supports vectorised operations, so `array & mask` will apply this to all elements with no need for explicit loops. All in all, your code could look like this.

```
MASK_ZERO = 0b11111100
MASK_EXTRACT = 0b00000011

cover_path = 's2.bmp'
secret_path = '2.jpeg'

# EMBED
cover = cv.imread(cover_path, 0)
secret = cv.imread(secret_path, 0)
secret = cv.resize(secret, (220, 220), interpolation=cv.INTER_NEAREST)

secret_bits = []
for pixel in secret.flatten():
    secret_bits.extend(((pixel >> 6) & MASK_EXTRACT,
                        (pixel >> 4) & MASK_EXTRACT,
                        (pixel >> 2) & MASK_EXTRACT,
                        pixel & MASK_EXTRACT))
secret_bits = np.array(secret_bits)
secret_length = len(secret_bits)

stego = cover.copy().flatten()
stego[:secret_length] = (stego[:secret_length] & MASK_ZERO) | secret_bits


# EXTRACT
extracted_bits = stego[:secret_length] & MASK_EXTRACT
extracted = []
for i in range(0, secret_length, 4):
    extracted.append((extracted_bits[i] << 6) |
                     (extracted_bits[i+1] << 4) |
                     (extracted_bits[i+2] << 2) |
                     extracted_bits[i+3])
extracted = np.array(extracted, dtype=np.uint8)
extracted = extracted.reshape(secret.shape)

print('Is extracted secret correct: {}'.format(np.all(secret == extracted)))
```

Comment: great, beautiful code. I see your logic. I had a gut feeling that I was doing something wrong when I got to that much string processing. Thank you very much.